# How to get the list of neighbours for a point shpapefile using R?

Tags: r

It is quite easy to get the list of neighbors for polygon shapefiles but I am unable to do the same operation for point shapefiles.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but if your question is about finding closest points, then yes: this is relatively easy. Much info can be found using the search.

Comment: yes, I would like to find the list of closest points, i.e., neighbors for a given point shapefile. The shapefile has numeric value and location name. After getting the neighbors' list, it would be easy for calculating spatial correlation like Moran's I.